# How to test production mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I've added a bundler to my ASP.NET Core project. Now I'm using the `<environment>` tag helpers to reference the bundled files in production mode.

```
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site-bundle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/layout-bundle.min.css" />
</environment>
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/layout/css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/layout/css/style.css" />
</environment>
```

But how do I test production mode. I thought doing a release build would suffice but it's still using the development version of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

With the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable set to Production or other value than Development.

Maybe you use a launchSettings.json file? Also, you can pass the variable as a command-line parameter in most cases. There are many options.

```
dotnet run ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** You need to add new Profile in launchsettings.json file.
[launchsettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joNSV.png)

**Step 2 :**
Set "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production".

**Step 3 :**

Run project with this Profile.
[Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq9un.png)

**Step : 4**
You show environment is now production.
[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQiqD.png)